# Cleaning up interface

Tags: interface

Is their some way of removing these useless tool buttons below the axis viewer. They are so often in the way.

In viewport gizmos one can toggle navigate but that removes all of this.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable Navigation Controls in Preferences > Interface > Editors

By the way, I find these buttons not useless at all

[image]

Comment: As a hotkey user the are more than useless, but thanks